# How can I temporarily disable javascript AFTER a page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to disable Javascript once a page has already loaded.

Why?

Because I want to test how the behavior of something like the following 'degrades' when javascript isn't available, but i dont want the hastle of going to the browser's top level Javascript enable/disable feature. In addition I specifically want to disable it **after the page has loaded** because I want to isolate my testing to how that one form would perform (I have jQuery running for the rest of the page and I don't want to lose that).

Allowing me to disable JS for this code allows me to test the form postback as well as the AJAX postback.

> `<form
>   action="/pseudovirtualdirectoryfortesting/company/Contact"
>   id="fooForm" method="post"
>   onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), {
>   insertionMode:
>   Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace,
>   loadingElementId: 'submitting',
>   onBegin: Function.createDelegate(this,
>   submitComments_begin), onComplete:
>   Function.createDelegate(this,
>   submitComments_complete), onFailure:
>   Function.createDelegate(this,
>   submitComments_failure), onSuccess:
>   Function.createDelegate(this,
>   submitComments_success) });">`

What plug-ins or tactics could I use. I want to be able to test in different browsers, and some projects I work on are designed only for one browser (not my fault) so I need as many possible solutions as there are.

Comment: @epascarello - yes and no. like I said i want to test just that specific form (thats what I'm working on). right now i don't want to worry about whats going on in the rest of the page. maybe someone else is working on making those components 'javascript-disabled' friendly :-) so i have my reasons :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox. With it you can disable Javascript at any time, disable cookies, css, whatever you want.

Comment: The developer toolbar didn't work for me. Specifically, trying to turn off javascript on the "My Libary" page of Google Books.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work anymore - at least for FF 12.0 and Web Developer 1.1.9 :(

Comment: Nowadays just open up Firefox dev tools, go to Settings -> Advanced -> Check Disable Javascript.

Comment: Settings -> Advanced -> Check Disable Javascript reloads the page. I need to disable it after it has rendered the content.

Comment: It's a pity that "modern" browsers don't support such a simple option. It used to work in old Opera. Vivaldi unfortunately doesn't have such option neither. For such tasks (and for everyday use as well) I just use [surf browser](https://surf.suckless.org/). But you need to patch and compile it per your needs by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Test in FireFox with the NoScript addon.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to write a separate answer on this question because I find this topic actually very important. And apparently my comment above hasn't been noticed.

In the past, functionality described:
"disable javascript after browser has rendered the content",
was easily accessible in Opera.

But independent Opera now is dead (now it's Chrome). And apparently there is almost no independent browser at all (google is the default search engine, and often you cannot replace it with your own search engine - duckduckgo would be probably much better alternative).

Well, one can consider that as just an opinion. But, well, It's pretty clear that dynamic-JS-toggle was removed from all major browser for a reason.

I've tried many popular browsers and there is no single one that provides such functionality.

Currently the only up-to-date solution is using surf browser and patch it a bit. Which is to change 1 into 0 in line:

```
setparameter(c, 1, (ParamName)a->i, &curconfig[a->i].val);
```

Surf (about, sources, patches):
https://surf.suckless.org/

Answer (score -2):

This is not answer to the generic question "how to disable javascript", but was a good solution for me.

I have stopped using Microsoft's AJAX in place of jQuery.

As a result of this I am using unobtrusive javascript and it is therefore much easier to disable just the AJAX handler for my form than it is with Microsoft Ajax.

All i do is comment out the line that hooks up the AJAX call to my submit button.

Comment: Downvote me on my own question after ten years ;-) Thx